# Why output is coming infinite loop

Tags: c, int, unsigned

why this question is entering in infinite loop. Acc to me ans should be 65001,65002....65535. Plesae elaborate.Thanks in advance

```
#include<>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned int i=65000;
 while ( i++ != 0 )
 printf("%d ",i);
 return 0;
 getch();
}
```

Comment: use `uint16_t` instead of `unsigned int`. BTW `getch();` : unreached code

Comment: It enters the loop because the condition in the loop `i++ != 0` is satisfied... `int` is not guaranteed to be a 16-bit unsigned integer. In fact, it is most 32-bit in nowadays computer. Use `uint16_t` or `unsigned short` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On modern systems, an unsigned int is at least 32 bits, but you are expecting 16 bits.  You don't have an infinite loop, but it won't wrap around until at least 2^32 (4294967296).